# Git for windows: fatal: open /dev/null or dup failed: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, git

After some weird bug (it happened a while ago, so I don't know what caused it) this started to happen to me.

Every time I try to use [git on windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) (installed 2.6.2 x64) I get:

```
fatal: open /dev/null or dup failed: No such file or directory.
```

I have googled this error, nowhere any answers or solutions.

Note I also can't use `git-bash` or `git-gui` either. PyCharm Git integration fails to use `git.exe` too and so does Github.

For time being I have a VM with Linux in it that kinda replaces git use for me, but I'd like to resolve this bug.

Comment: Sounds like they're having the same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25590972/151502)